# If I was asked to define what a "file storage block" is, what should my answer be?

Tags: unix, filesystems

A question says "Define a file storage block with reference to the physical file system in UNIX".

1. What is the difference between a file storage block and a storage block?
2. What is the answer that I should write for this question?

Comment: What do the course materials have to say about the issue?  I'm not convinced there's a difference between 'storage block' and 'file storage block', but I've not read your course materials either.  I'd probably answer "the basic quantum of storage allocation on the file system — the size on a given file system is usually fixed, but different file systems may have different storage block sizes; it is often a power of 2 between 512 bytes and 8 KiB".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not clear that it's specifically related to programming or software development.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The course material is as clear as the question itself (which is not too much). Your answer is the one that I will probably give if asked about this matter further.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Just what is "the physical file system in UNIX"?  You should answer based on [LTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_Tape_File_System).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you. Very helpful.